# Improve the security of SESSION variables

Tags: php, security

I have some doubt. This script is supposed to be protected from public access via an authentication method. Do you think that it's doing its work properly? Is it safe to do so? What do you think is missing or should be added? Thank you for helping me.

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['USER'])) {
    header('Location: /login.php');
    return false;
}

header('Content-Type: text/html');
readfile('/path/to/protected/data');
```

Comment: that also depends on how you (un)set sessions ...

Comment: `return false` ?? ?? u can also add `ELSE` part, or move data part in condition rather then depending on `if(!isset($_SESSION['USER'])) {`

Comment: Using session you do not secure "session" but secure access to particular part in the application

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['USER']) && !empty($_SESSION['USER'])){header('Content-Type: text/html');
readfile('/path/to/protected/data');}` its better then to yours

Comment: _“Do you think that it's doing its work properly?”_ - impossible to tell, because we don’t even know if `/path/to/protected/data` is below or above the document root, and if below, whether it might still be requestable via the web server’s default mechanisms, without taking a detour via this script.

Comment: @devpro if you're doing `!empty()` you don't need the `isset()` do you?

Comment: @treyBake: correct, actually i write isset first :p